# After installing Laravel version 5.6 via composer and windows 10 show me 5.5.32

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.6

I trying to install last version (5.6) of `Laravel` project but after install that, It was not version 5.6 but it is 5.5.32 !!!

I installed composer on my windows 10 and I did run `composer global require "laravel/installer"` and `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog` according to https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/installation

But when checking laravel version installed it show me 5.5.32 !! why??

I using XAMPP and `PHP > 7.1`

Answer (score 0):

last version Laravel is `dev-develop`

trying to run in CMD :

`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog dev-develop`

you must installed composer and php 7.2

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using at least PHP 7.1.3 and update your composer.json file to:

```
"php": ">=7.1.3",
"laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
```

Then run:

> composer update