# Laravel new command installing Laravel 5.5 instead of Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.6

I am facing a problem with new version of Laravel. Laravel 5.6 has been released recently. I am trying to install it with this command

```
laravel new blog
```

Everytime I tried this it's installing Laravel 5.5. I tried to clear the composer cache with this command

```
composer clear-cache
```

But still has the same problem.

When I try this

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog dev-develop
```

It's installing a dev version of Laravel 5.6

Comment: Very funny. I have asked this question 5 days ago from now and the other question was asked 3 days ago. This one is not duplicate, that one is duplicate. @patricus

Comment: Yes, I know the times are a little off, but that one was the first question to accept an answer, so all of the "unanswered" duplicates get marked as duplicates (there's more than one). My OCD doesn't like it either, but that's how it goes.

Comment: The question was also asked [14 days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48411868/after-installing-laravel-version-5-6-via-composer-and-windows-10-show-me-5-5-32). So, even then, this question is a duplicate of that one. But again, no accepted answer, so it gets marked as the duplicate.

Comment: But, it's all moot now anyway. Laravel 5.6 was officially released today, so the installer and composer will now use 5.6.

Comment: @patricus Thanks for the release information. By the way, what if I accept an answer now?

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is wrong, as you can see at the [github releases page](https://github.com/laravel/framework/releases), Laravel 5.6 is not yet officially released.

As Taylor Otwell (Laravel's creator) stated [on his twitter](https://twitter.com/taylorotwell/status/958725579066499072) he plans to release Laravel 5.6 after his Laracon online talk.

For now you can use laravel's installer with the `--dev` option to create a Laravel 5.6 project.

```
laravel new blog --dev=true
```

Comment: Is Laravel 5.6 still in development?

Answer (score 0):

Change Laravel version  in `coposer.json`

```
"require": {

    "laravel/framework": "5.6.*", //<-- here
```

Then try to run `composer update` command

Comment: I tried, it gives my this error `The requested package laravel/framework 5.6.* is satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.6.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.`